# Cross check values betwen 2 columns in Excel

Tags: excel, match, lookup

I have a query for matching values in Excel between two columns.
i.e. column C and H;

There are common values between the two columns and I need to see what values from H are missing from column C (probably highlighting the missing values) or vice versa.
What would be the correct expression?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer worked for you or if you have any issues with the answer. Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered

Answer (score 0):

You add conditional formatting based on a formula like below

```
=IFNA(IF(H2=VLOOKUP(H2|C:C|1|FALSE)|TRUE|FALSE)|FALSE)
```

See the below image for reference.
[image]

So here I've highlighted the values found; to do the reverse, you should use the below formula

```
=IFNA(IF(H2=VLOOKUP(H2|C:C|1|FALSE)|FALSE|TRUE)|TRUE)
```